# How to programatically open a dialog box in primefaces without user click?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am working on an exam management session using Java EE 7 and Primefaces. Tests are timed and once the time is over, I want to display a dialog box automatically(i.e. without user clicking any button). I successfully used Primefaces Dialog framework on the click of a button, but can't do it automatically.

For timing the test I am using TimerService, which calls a stateless EJB's method on timeout. I have a session scoped CDI bean which creates the timer.

This is the post construct method of the CDI bean.

```
public void init()  {

    studentAnswers = new ArrayList<StudentAnswer>();

    examSections=ePaper.getSections();

    examTimerBean.createExamPaperDuration(10,RequestContext.getCurrentInstance());

}
```

The stateless EJB is as follows -

```
@Stateless
public class ExamTimerBean {

@Resource TimerService timerService;
RequestContext reqCtx;

public void createExamPaperDuration(int duration,RequestContext reqCtx){

    this.reqCtx=reqCtx;
    timerService.createTimer(duration*1000, null);

}

@Timeout
public void examTimeExpired(){// throws IOException{

    try{

    reqCtx.openDialog("thanks");

    }
    catch(EJBException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

I am passing the request context to the EJB, but the dialogBox doesn't open. Kindly help.

Comment: You need to do it on the web layer itself anyway. You are not supposed to pass `RequestContext` itself to an upper service layer. It is a web layer thing and should be done precisely in its own place. Additionally, doing so increases the coupling among modules unnecessarily.

Comment: Like @Tiny says: you're going about it all wrong. Your EJB should have nothing to do with displaying the dialog. Also the `RequestContext` is out of place here. Like the name implies, it's associated with a HTTP request; initiating an operation from the back does not follow standard HTTP, hence, there's no active `RequestContext`. Your options are to either poll the back end periodically, or use Server-sent events (HTML-5 only) to push the notification.

Comment: @Tiny,@kolossus Thanks for your inputs. Working on the solution.

Comment: I would use PF push for this... Works great in combination with async ejb3.1 or ejb timers